# Does gilding reduce or increase the cost of the hero?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I heard that you can "gild" all heroes in clickerheroes.com, which gives them 50% more efficiency per gild.

Now I ask myself, does this in any way affect the amount of gold you need to upgrade the gilded hero?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither. The gild status does not change the cost of your hero, it only increases it's damage.